# Multivariate Polynomial Feature generation

Tags: linear-regression

I don't quite seem to understand the rules used to create the polynomial features when trying to find a polynomial model with Linear Regression in the multivariate setting.

Let's say I have a two predictor variables `a` and `b`. When generating polynomial features (for example using [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html)) I get 6 features for degree 2: `y = bias + a + b + a * b + a^2 + b^2`

This much I understand. 
When I set the degree to 3 I get 10 features instead of my expected 8. I expected it to be this: `y = bias + a + b + a * b + a^2 + b^2 + a^3 + b^3`

**What is the general formula of generating multivariate features? How does this look like in the 3rd degree?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[General Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51906400/12886603) is as follow:
 \begin{equation} N(n,d)=C(n+d,d) \end{equation} where n is the number of the features, $d$ is the degree of the polynomial, $C$ is binomial coefficient(combination).

Example with vector (2,3) to 3rd degree :

```
x = np.array[[2,3]]
pf = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3, include_bias=True)
pf.fit_transform(x)
```

returns :

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  9.,  8., 12., 18., 27.]])
```

wich is : [1, $\:$ $x_1$, $\:$ $x_2$,
 $\:$ $x_1^2$,$\:$ $x_1x_2$, $\:$ $x_2^2$,
 $\:$ $x_1^3$, $\:$ $x_2x_1^2$, $\:$ $x_2^2 x_1$, $\:$ $x_2^3$]

You can see this as expanding this equation and throwing out the coefficients :

\begin{equation}1 + (x_1 + x_2) +  (x_1 + x_2)^2 +  (x_1 + x_2)^3 \end{equation}